# How does one make a source folder project to be "public" in ProjectLocker?

Tags: version-control, projectlocker

When creating a new project in ProjectLocker, by default it makes the project private, and you have to explicitly add people to the project.  What if you simply want to make the project public.  Seems like you should be able to do it, but the UI is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All ProjectLocker repositories are private at this time.  ProjectLcoker does not have a notion of a public project that people can access.